# Can't change title while JQuery tooltip is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is the scenario:

1. I create a button using JQuery [button](http://jqueryui.com/button/) widget, and I add a title to it
2. I call JQuery tooltip [widget](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

When I change the title pragmatically, the tooltip updates correctly, but when I change the title **while I'm hovering the button** the title attribute doesn't change (I checked it on firebug)
Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AXTMG/) that illustrates this use case.

In my example, if you click [change title] button it works, to see the problem, click [change title with delay] and put the cursor on the [subject button] and wait for the alert.

In a nutshell, this code doesn't work while hovering the button:

```
$('#div').attr('title', 'new title');
```

This looks very weird for me, can anyone advise?

To be more accurate, my question is: **why to title attribute doesn't change?**

Comment: You need to trigger the tooltip again to refresh it - http://jsfiddle.net/AXTMG/1/

Comment: No @luke! Triggering the tooltip again updates the tooltip but **doesn't update the title** check on firebug, you'll find that the title attribute didn't changed

Comment: @skafandri if you apply a widget plugin to the element that manages an attribute you need to work within the API of the plugin. Whatever shows up in html view becomes irrelevant. The title is stored in data

Comment: @charlietfl but why it works just fine when the mouse is not hovering the button? Makes sense?

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/AXTMG/2/ -- it destroys the tooltip and the reactivates it.

Comment: @luke I don't care about the tooltip, I want to be able to set the **title attribute** while the tooltip is active (I need the title attribute for another plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but you could do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
       $(document).tooltip('destroy');
       $('#div').attr('title','new title');
       $(document).tooltip();
        alert('title changed');
    }, 2000);
 });
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/WMV9h/)